# Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $K$, and $S\subseteq V$.
Suppose $S = \{\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2,\dots,\vec{v}_n\}$ has the property that for each $v \in V$, there exist unique scalars $ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \in K$ such that: $$\vec{v} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\vec{v}_i$$
Show that $S$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: What is your definition of a basis of a vector space? Write it down and compare!

Comment: i can see that S clearly spans V but i cant seem to prove linear independence

Comment: $0$ can be expressed *uniquely* as a linear combination - so assume it is linearly dependent, then what happens?

Comment: we have 0=a1v1,.......,anvn with not all ai=0 ??

Answer (score 1):

Suppose to the contrary, that $S$ is not a basis. So $S$ is linearly dependent and we have $\vec{0}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\vec{v}_i$ with not all $a_i=0$ as the unique representation of $\vec{0}$ in terms of $S$.

Now take any $\vec{w}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i\vec{v}_i$ - this representation is by hypothesis unique too, BUT what happens when you now express $\vec{w}=\vec{w}+\vec{0}$ in terms of $S$?

Comment: thanks alot it seems so simple now